# Unable to read property file by property-placeholder in Spring. Getting The system cannot find the file specified error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, property-placeholder

When I tried to load property file which is in the source code, I am getting issues. But when I tried to load property file externally, it working fine. Mentioned both working and not working code below. Can someone help me on this. I am a very new bee to Spring :)

The only change I did for loading property file from external and within the project is location declaration in context:property-placeholder.

Configured spring context to load property file from external as below. It worked very well.

When loaded property file from externally - **working** :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/Test/Data/WebDetails.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" />
```

I configured my property file to load from project in a spring context as below - **Not Working**:

```
<bean id="webProperties" class="com.test.run.WebProperties" />

<context:property-placeholder location="file:./src/main/resources/WebDetails.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" />
```

My WebDetails.properties is place in Maven Project under src/main/resources. And file looks like

```
url = www.testresponse.com
space = SampleSpace
```

And am mapping property values in WebProperties like below

```
@Component
public class WebProperties{
   @Value("{url}") public String url;
   @Value("{space}") public String space;

   //getters
}
```

My Main class is :

```
public class ProcessWeb {
    ApplicationContext context;
    WebProperties webProperties;

}

public ProcessWeb () {
     context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("web-context.xml");
     webProperties= (WebProperties) context.getBean("webProperties");
    }

public void execute(String[] args){
    webProperties.getURL()
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    ProcessWeb main = new ProcessWeb ();
    main.execute();
}
```

When I executed my main class when load properties from code. I am getting error as **${url}  (The system cannot find the file specified.)**

How Should I configure My location path in placeholder?

**More Info** : Main class, ProcessWeb , will be called from a batch file. After deploying the code, when we executing that batch file from command prompt, am getting same issue for external properties as well. Is any configuration need to be change? We are packaging our code into jar files

Answer (score 2):

Use `classpath` like:

```
location="classpath:WebDetails.properties"
```

Comment: I tried this before. It is working when executing from code. But from command line it was not working.


**More Info :** Main class, ProcessWeb , will be called from a batch file. After deploying the code, when we executing that batch file from command prompt, am getting same issue. Is any configuration need to be change? We are packaging our code into jar files.

Comment: @User0234 both Main class and ProcessWeb need to have the WebDetails.properties. Or at least which of the jar needs it. Check or contents of your jar files. maybe the properties file is not present the jar.